# How to integrate Instamojo payment gateway in laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel-4, instamojo

I have done it in case of paypal.
Is there any way to integrate instamojo like this?

"require": {

```
"laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
"moltin/laravel-cart": "dev-master",
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
```

}

Comment: Currently we don't have plugin for Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a package called **Indian Payment Gateway** (indipay) by which you can configure payment gateways like CCAvenue, PayUMoney, EBS, CitrusPay, **Instamojo** recently I have used this package for the integration and succeeded. The below link has a clear steps to do the integration process.
[Github link](https://github.com/softon/indipay/tree/laravel4)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This gateway can be used to configure Instamojo in Laravel 4.2